# ng-repeat filter by date in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have an ng-repeat with dates in there like this :

```
<small>Added: <strong>{{format(contents.completeddate)}}</strong></small>
```

and im using a datepicker plugin which basically gives me 2 objects, a startdate and an end date.

contents.completeddate for example could equal 
"10/02/2016"

In my controller i have :

```
$scope.main.daterange= {startDate: moment().subtract(7,'d'), endDate: moment()};
```

but this can by changed by my html obviously, im just setting previous 7 days as the default. Is there a way in my ng-repeat to filter the contents.completeddate by date range if it's between

> $scope.main.daterange.startDate

and

> $scope.main.daterange.endDate

Answer (score 0):

Please ref This May Be You Will Get Idea..

[angularjs filter not filter multipe filter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244804/angularjs-filter-not-filter-multipe-filter-value)

Comment: Its more like a between rather than a multiple mate